# Dynamic Markdown Document That Updates When Linked Code Updates

Tags: python, json, markdown

I need to write a markdown-based interface control document that dynamically reflects changes to a python file with some json object formatting in it. For example when the data type `wheelSize` changes from int to float in the json, the markdown file's description of `wheelSize` saying "ensure you use a datatype of ___ for wheelSize" changes the datatype too.

example_file_with_json.py

```
"properties": {
                "wheelSize": {"type": "int"},
```

This was a related question: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/tx5oyt/comment/i3kf8no/